# ASP.NET 3.5 GridView Row Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a  `GridView`.  I have to collect the `GridViewRow` where checkbox is selected.  How can I achieve it without any client side script?  Please help me to get this done.

Comment: Posting the code what you have so far would make things easy for the people who want to answer you question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you   are familiar  with  LINQ,you  can   get   this   something  like

```
List<GridViewRow> rowCollection = 
                     GridView1.Rows
                     .OfType<GridViewRow>()
                     .Where(x => ((CheckBox)x.FindControl("chkRow")).Checked)
                     .Select(x => x).ToList();
```

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative old-school method is to iterate through the Rows collection of the grid with for or foreach cycle, find the checkboxes with the FindControl method and check their Checked property value.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy to understand when you come back to it later.

```
 var selectedRows = (from GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows
                    let cbx = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1")
                    where cbx.Checked
                    select row).ToList();
```

Bare in mind that for this to work I think you'll need to convert the column containing the checkbox into a template column.